# What is a prayer by a Vaishnava saint in honour of Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, vaishnavism

For example, the Rudrashtakam occurs in the Uttara Kanda of Ramacharitmanas, which is composed by Sri Tulsidasa Goswami, who is a Rama Bhakt. I have heard he praise Lord Shiva several times in the work. Also all the demigods including Lord Sri Krishna himself pray to Lord Shiva in the Srimad Bhaagavatam (compiled by Vyasadeva) to request him to save them from the poison from verse 8.7.21 (https://prabhupadabooks.com/sb/8/7/21) to 8.7.35 (https://prabhupadabooks.com/sb/8/7/35). What are some other prayers devoted to Lord Shiva coming from a Vaishnava source? Please name the source as well.

EDIT : The commenters are telling me to say that questions asking for a list are too broad, so if you can name even one prayer each (along with the source), that will do.

Comment: Questions which require list like answers are too broad...

Comment: @YDS - How does this require a list? I doubt there are many such prayers. Just mention a few along with the source.

Comment: @TigerShroff then edit your question to limit to specific!

Comment: It would be good if people gave a reason for downvoting. I've provided relevant information and the question is quite specific.

Comment: Why are you giving some examples then asking for "other" examples? You are partly answering the title question. I would remove all the examples and ask a straightforward question or change the title to match with what you've written.

Comment: @sv. - To set the tone of the kind of prayers and the kind of sources I want. Why should I remove the examples? I want people to know that these are the prayers I already know about, and that they should put some other prayers in their answer.

Comment: "What are some other prayers devoted to Lord Shiva coming from a Vaishnava source?" - this should be the title. Not "What are some prayers Vaishnava saints have composed in honour of Lord Shiva?" - which is confusing especially you've answered it yourself. I'm not the one who downvoted but just speculating why some others might have downvoted. Self-answering questions are not good questions.